# GAS - Get video Id from YouTube history playlist

Tags: google-apps-script, youtube-api

I'm trying to get the Id's of watched videos. I am not sure if that is possible, and when I test the length of the result I get 0.
Here is what I have so far:

```
var result = YouTube.PlaylistItems.list('snippet', {playlistId: 'HL'});
Logger.log(result.length)
```

Is this possible? What am I missing?

Comment: From what I have seen, everyone has `[watchHistory] => HL` as watch history. So if there was a call (which I have not seen as yet) , you would need to use the channel id as the main call with 'HL' as option call.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I'm glad to know that what I'm trying to do is achievable. I'm not familiar with the youtube API, what I have so far regarding the extraction of video ID's from the watch history is what I posted. It's not much, but I'm not giving up.